# Mule S3 connector Cloudhub deployment issue

Tags: amazon-s3, mule, mule-component, cloudhub

I am trying to deploy one application in which I am using S3 connector. Its working fine while deploying locally. 
But however it failed to deploy on cloudhub after maven build.
It showing error as below:

> Your application has failed with exception
>   com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.v3.dto.DeploymentException: Line 18 in XML
>   document from URL [file:/opt/mule/mule-3.8.6/apps/myapp/s3-test.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/s3":config}'.

I have added dependency in the POM & verified the schema namespace in my XML file as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom file, you need to add this s3 dependency in the **plugin inclusions** section as well.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
        <inclusions>
            <inclusion>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-s3</artifactId>
            </inclusion>
            ....
            ....
            ....
            ....
        </inclusions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```